Significance of tangent passing through the origin in graphical interpretation
(This question was asked in CSIR NET June 2019 examination)
A monkey climbs a tree to eat fruits. The amount of energy spent climbing on the different branches has a relationship, as shown in the figure below:

The ratio of the energy gained to energy spent will be maximum at which point?
The answer states it is at the point on the curve where the tangent passes through the origin.
Complete question link is here.
My doubt is: There's no data to support the reasoning of the answer. It could have been any other random point, say where the slope is unity may be. So, how was the answer particularly concluded?  Please suggest.

What’s the original question?

@DavidQuinn Edited. Pardon the inconvenience. Please have a look.

If $r=\frac{y}{x}$, then the required maximum occurs when $\frac{dr}{dx}=0$
You have $$\frac{dr}{dx}=\frac{xy’-y}{x^2}=0\implies y’=\frac{y}{x}$$
So the gradient of the tangent at the point $(x,y)$ is the same as the gradient of the line joining the origin and the point with coordinates $(x,y)$
Which is effectively what the answer is saying.

+1 for the answer. Pity, I failed to observe it!
